# Convert object feature into float

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm trying to run a DecisionTreeClassifier on the Kaggle titanic database. (https://www.kaggle.com/rahulsah06/titanic?select=train.csv)

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
```

```
titanic_file_path = '../input/titanic/train.csv'
titanic_data = pd.read_csv(titanic_file_path)

#I create X and y
features= ['Pclass', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp',
       'Parch', 'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked']
X= titanic_data[features]
y = titanic_data.Survived

#Split into validation and training data
train_X, val_x, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(X,y, random_state=1)

#model definition and fit
titanic_model = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1)
titanic_model.fit(train_X, train_y)
```

But when I run the code I get an error:

```
could not convert string to float: 'female'
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: you can't use the data and simply train a ML model. You have to do proper pre-processing of the features. Which is absent in your code

Comment: There are literally dozens of detailed tutorials on this - see for example https://www.kaggle.com/alexisbcook/titanic-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix is to convert your columns to categorial values using the get_dummies method.

```
X = pd.get_dummies(X)
```

Although probably you should take more preprocessing steps than you currently are. But for a toy run, I guess get dummies will suffice.